# MX Player how to set a playlist?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to tell the player my playlist of files, but it doesn't work.

```
val names = ArrayList<String>()
val files = ArrayList<String>()

for (i in 0 until playlist.length()) {
    val item = playlist.getJSONObject(i)

    if (item.getInt("index") >= index) {
        names.add(item.getString("title"))
        files.add(item.getString("stream_url"))

        Log.i(App.TAG, item.getString("title"))
    }
}

intent.putStringArrayListExtra("video_list", files)
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("video_list.name", names)

//doesn't work to
intent.putExtra("video_list", files)
intent.putExtra("video_list.name", names)
```

I read the documentation for how to install a playlist: https://mx.j2inter.com/api

What can I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Just replace ArrayList  with Uri []. This code works good for Mx player

```
Uri[] video_list = new Uri[5]{};
String[] video_list_name = new String[5]{};

String[0] = "First video name"
String[1] = "Second video name"

videos[0] = Uri.parse(Your video url)
videos[1] = Uri.parse(Another video url)


intent.putExtra("video_list.name", video_list_name)
intent.putExtra("video_list", video_list)
```